# Logstash: since_db not getting created

Tags: logstash, logstash-file, logstash-configuration

Was playing with the `since_db` option and it appears that the sincedb file isn't getting created. Below is my Logstash `File` configuration. I have verified that I can create the file manually so there is no permission issue. Would appreciate if anyone can throw more light on the same.

```
input {
 file {
  path => "/home/tom/fileData/*.log"
  type => "log"
  sincedb_path => "/home/tom/sincedb"
  start_position => beginning
 }
}
```

Comment: Anything interesting in the Logstash log (you may have to increase verbosity with `--verbose` or `--debug`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can the user running `logstash` write to the `sincedb_path` location, if not that is what needs to get fixed. Other than that, your `logstash` configuration should work fine.